# Laravel - Request Null

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to request the $year off my form in my show method but it's returning null. I'm logging time entries and I want to query the times by years like this: `$times = Time::where('user_id', $id)->whereYear('start_day', $request->year)->get();`. This query works inside of my getReports method, but not in my show method which Is where I want it to work. If I dd($request->all()) inside of my show method It just returns an empty array. I'm not sure how to fix this, I believe it has to do with my route getReport. Is there a way to pass those values into the show method? I just need the $request->year to work so I can query properly.

Routes:

```
Route::resource('admin/reports', 'Admin\ReportController', [ 'as' => 'admin'])->middleware('admin');
Route::post('admin/reports/getReport', 'Admin\ReportController@getReport')->name('admin.getReport')->middleware('admin');
```

Form POST:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.getReport') }}">
```

Controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Helper\ReportHelper;
use App\Time;
use App\User;
use App\Category;
use App\Offtime;

use Carbon\Carbon;

use Auth;
use Date;
use PDF;
use Session;


class ReportController extends Controller
{

    public function create() {

        $users = User::all();
        $times = Time::all();
        $years = array();

        $length_times = count($times);
        for($i=0;$i<$length_times;$i++){
            $year = Carbon::parse($times[$i]->start_day)->format('Y');
            array_push($years, $year);
        }

        $years = array_unique($years);

        return view('admin.report.create', compact('users', 'years'));
    }

    public function show($id, Request $request) {

        $user = User::find($id);
        if (!$user) {
            return false;
        }

        $times = Time::where('user_id', $id)->get(); 

        return view ('admin.report.show', compact('user','times')
    }

    public function getReport(Request $request) {
        $form_user = $request->form_user;
        $year = $request->year;

        if (!$form_user) {
            return abort(404);
        }
        $user = User::find($form_user);
        if ($user) {
            return redirect()->route('admin.reports.show', $user->id);
        }
        return abort(404);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For default show uses GET method and you are trying to make a POST.
getReport you defined as post, that's why it's working.

More information about route resource

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers

Comment: Ok I switched it to GET and now it's working except it's returning this error now.

```The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given.```

Comment: @stormakt because your `show` method is returning `false` not a response or string or anything that could be converted to a response

Comment: How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I prefer to use `Route Model Binding`

```php
public function show(User $user) {

        $times = Time::where('user_id', $user->id)->get(); 

        return view ('admin.report.show', compact('user','times')
    }
```

This will handel if the `user` does not exist.